# How to autogenerate two values when inserting at runtime?

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis as DB framework in JAVA and I'm trying to generate automatically two values when inserting rows in a table: the task id and another value. This is my query:

```
<insert id="insertTwoValuesSequentialluy" parameterType="com.example.autogenerated.Task" >
  <selectKey resultType="java.lang.String" keyProperty="taskId" order="BEFORE" >
      select MY_TASK_ID_SEQUENCE.nextval from dual
  </selectKey>  
  insert into DYDA_D.TASK_TABLE (taskId, otherVariable, autogeneratedValue)
  values ( #{taskId,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, 
           #{otherVariable,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
           MY_SECOND_SEQUENCE.nextval = #{autogeneratedValue,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
</insert>
```

The code works fine but I'm having the following problem: while at runtime the Task instance gets its member *taskId* setted, it doesn't happen the same with *autogeneratedValue*, although when I check the database I can see the column matching *autogeneratedValue* isn't null for this new row. How can I get *autogeneratedValue* setted at runtime with no need of making a select query?

PS: don't pay attention to commas and the like, I have lots of columns and I've deleted most of them and changed names on the rest for this snippet. My point with the code is for you to see how I've generated the values, tags I've used etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
<insert id="insertTwoValuesSequentialluy" 
      parameterType="com.example.autogenerated.Task" 
      useGeneratedKeys="true"
      keyProperty="taskId,autogeneratedValue"
      keyColumn="taksId,autogeneratedValue">
  insert into DYDA_D.TASK_TABLE (taskId, otherVariable, autogeneratedValue)
  values (MY_TASK_ID_SEQUENCE.nextval, 
          #{otherVariable,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
          MY_SECOND_SEQUENCE.nextval)
</insert>
```

Comment: is it id or taskId within attribute keyColumn?

Comment: I'm getting a SQLException: This function is not supported, error code[17023]

Comment: I've mistyped - keyColumn should contain comma separated list of columns and keyProperty comma separated list of corresponding properties.

Comment: Probably. But SQL insert statement in your question implies that column name for task identifier is taskId and the other column name is autogeneratedValue.